#  Parse out measurements (L x W x H) in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to regex a string in PHP with `preg_match_all` to find parts and populate a database.  I have most of it worked out but the only part that Im hung up on is finding the measurements portion:

Here is my string:

> "NA153 - Fire Bowl Fabricated From a Vintage Propane Tank, Would Work as A Water Feature or a Glass Top Could be Added for an Unusual Coffee Table as Well, 23H x 39W - $1200.00"

Here is My reg ex so far:

```
"%([A-Z0-9]{5}) #Find Sku
\s*\-?\s*
(.*)\s*\, # Find Title
\s*
.*([0-9][HWD])\s*\-? #Find Dimensions
\s*
\$([0-9\.]*) # Find Price
%x"
```

It finds sku, title, and price correctly.  But dimensions it is returning only 1 "9W"

here is my function call:

```
preg_match_all('{{regular expression}}', '{{string}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated as I am new to regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw a `+` quantifier after the `[0-9]` group for dimensions, like so:

```
"%([A-Z0-9]{5}) #Find Sku
\s*\-?\s*
(.*)\s*\, # Find Title
\s*
.*([0-9]+[HWD])\s*\-? #Find Dimensions
\s*
\$([0-9\.]*) # Find Price
%x"
```

That `+` quantifier will cause it to greedily find as many numbers as it can before continuing to the `[HWD]`.

**Edit**: Sorry, that will only get you `39W'. To make it grab more than one dimension, you need to change it further:

```
'/([A-Z0-9]{5}) #Find Sku
\s*\-?\s*
(.*)\s*\, # Find Title
\s*
.*?([0-9]+[HWD](?:\s+x\s+[0-9]+[HWD])*)\s*\-? #Find Dimensions
\s*
\$([0-9\.]*) # Find Price
%/'
```

Comment: +1 almost there. Note I made some edits about greediness, single quotes, and parenthesis.

Comment: The `?` after the `.*` was a good edit, I didn't notice that until I threw it into a tester. However, I'm putting the parentheses back to how they were -- my assumption (which could be wrong!) is that the OP wants all the dimensions in one capture group. (so for example, `23H x 39W` would be captured in one group)

Comment: Yah, one capture group is what im hoping for, but i'll take anything

Comment: That edited regex should do it for you. See it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/8noIa7SMNQ

Answer (score 0):

If dimensions can be decimals, you could use:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)+[HWD](?:\s+x\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+[HWD])*)\s*-? #Find Dimensions
```